# Show that the following are equivalent:

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

If $f$ is a continuous function on a bounded set $S$, show that the following are equivalent:

> (a) the function $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$.
>
> (b) it is possible to extend $f$ to a continuous function on the set $\text{cl}(S)$.

Comment: I think to go from b) to a) you need that $cl(S)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

$$a) \Rightarrow b)$$
I assume we are working in normed spaces. The proof is completely the same for metric spaces.
Let $f:S \rightarrow F$ where F is complete. The assumption that F be complete is necessary.

**A) Construction of $g: cl(S) \rightarrow F $ such that $g|_{S} = f$.**

Let $\epsilon >0$.
$f$ is uniformly continuous so: $$\exists \delta >0: \forall ||y-x||< \delta \Rightarrow ||f(y)-f(x)||< \epsilon\: \: \text{for} \: \: x,y \in S \:\:\: (1)$$
Take a $u \in cl(S)$ and fix this element. We know that $S$ is dense in $cl(S)$. So there exists a sequence ${({a}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $S$ such that $${a}_{n} \: {\longrightarrow} \: u \:\text{for} \: n \longrightarrow \infty$$
We know by convergence of ${a}_{n}$:
$$\exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall p,q>N: ||{a}_{p}-{a}_{q}|| < \delta$$
f is continuous so for such $p$ and $q$ we know from (1):
$$||f({a}_{p}) - f({a}_{q})||<\epsilon$$
To summarise:
$$ \forall \epsilon>0,\exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall p,q>N: ||f({a}_{p})-f({a}_{q})|| < \epsilon$$
So ${(f({a}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $F$. So this has a limit let's call it: $g(u)$.

We have found for every $u \in cl(S)$ a $g(u)$.

**B) We show that $g(u)$ is independent of the sequence ${({a}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ we have chosen in part A)**

Take another sequence ${({b}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $S$ such that
$${b}_{n} \: {\longrightarrow} \: u \:\text{for} \: n \longrightarrow \infty$$
By the same argument as before we see that ${(f({b}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $F$. We have:
$$||g(u)-f({b}_{n})|| \leq ||g(u)-f({a}_{n})|| + ||f({b}_{n})-f({a}_{n})|| $$
for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We can find $M>0$ such that $$\forall n \geq M: ||{b}_{n}-u||<\frac{\delta}{2} \text{and}  ||{a}_{n}-u||<\frac{\delta}{2}$$
So $$||{b}_{n}-{a}_{n}|| \leq ||{a}_{n}-u||+||{b}_{n}-u||<\delta$$
This implies by (1): $$||f({b}_{n})-f({a}_{n})||<\epsilon$$
We know that ${(f({a}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $g(u)$, so by taking $n>M $ big enough we get:
$$||f({b}_{n})-g(u)||  \leq ||f({b}_{n})-f({a}_{n})||+||g(u) -f({a}_{n})||<2 \epsilon$$
So ${(f({b}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $g(u)$.
So we can define: $$g: cl(S) \rightarrow F:u \rightarrow g(u)$$

**C) g is continuous on cl(S)**

We have proven in B) that for every sequence ${({b}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $S$, ${(f({b}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $g(u)$. This shows that g is continuous on $S$. We still have to prove that $g$ is continuous on cl(S).

Take $x \in cl(S)$. We show that $g$ is continuous in $x$. 
So take a sequence ${({x}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $cl(S)$ wich converges to $x \in cl(S)$. Cause $S$ is dense in $cl(S)$, we know that for every ${x}_{n}$, there exists an element $y_{n} \in S$ such that $$||y_{n}-x_{n}||<\frac{\delta}{2}$$
And there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\forall n>N: ||x_{n}-x||<\frac{\delta}{2}$$
From these inequalities one can see that $$\forall n> N: ||x-y_{n}||< \delta$$
From the continuity of $f$:
$$\forall n> N: ||f(x)-f(y_{n})||< \epsilon$$
But also:
$$\forall n> N: ||f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})||< \epsilon$$

The last step:
$$||f(x_{n}) - f(x)|| \leq ||f(x_{n}) - f(y_{n})|| + ||f(x) - f(y_{n})||< 2\epsilon $$
So we have the following:
$$(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  \: \xrightarrow{n \longrightarrow \infty} \: x \:\Rightarrow \: (f(x_{n}))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  \: \xrightarrow{n \longrightarrow \infty} \: f(x)$$
So $g$ is continuous at $x$, hence $g$ is continuous.

**D) The uniqueness**

The uniqueness follows from the construction of $g$. $g$ was constructed by limits of sequences. These limits are unique so $g$ is unique to.